# Copy specific file using Shutil Copytree and ignore_patterns

Tags: python, shutil

I have been using shutil.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir) but I am not sure if it would work for what I need. When using Shutil Copy tree, I would like to copy only specific file names instead of ignoring specific file names. From different searches, the common optional parameter to ignore certain files would be:

```
ignore_patterns = ['global','dev','stg','prd']
shutil.copytree(src_dir, dst_dir, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns(*ignore_patterns))
```

I need the opposite of what this code is doing. Instead of ignoring "ignore_patterns" I would like to just copy the ignore_patterns. Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to do that. Like, you can find all gif files that contains global at first.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('global*.gif')
```

This glob will return a list that contains your matching pattern file directory. Then, iterating the list you have to Copy them.